# Is boost compressed matrix thread safety?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, openmp, sparse-matrix

I'm using openMP on boost compressed matrix container. I wonder if it is thread safe to use in this way?

```
int noOfUser=2649429;//2649429
    int noOfItem=17770;//17770;
    boost::numeric::ublas::compressed_matrix<int> ratingMatrix(noOfItem,noOfUser,110000000);
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic)
for(int i=0;i<noOfItem;i++)
{
  for(int j=0;j<noOfUser;j++)
  {
    ratingMatrix(i,j)= #some rating
  }
}
```

Comment: I strongly doubt it is safe. Almost no containers, except for simple vectors, are safe to modify in parallel.

Comment: Even if they are accessing different elements?

Answer (score -1):

My test result shows it is thread safe if inserting using coordinate